# Looking for framework for plotting scientific data: 2d/3d

Tags: c#, math, charts, bitmap

I need to visualize some scientific calculations. I generally prefer reusing code if there is already a good available instead of inventing wheels each time, that's why I am asking. I need a C# code to draw charts (just outputting a bitmap is ok) of 2d `(y=f(x))` and 3d `(z=f(x,y))` digital data sets (where any axis can be float, int or datetime), sometimes combined.

If I go [here](http://www.steema.com/gallery/charts/12#) and click 3D in the navigation bar on the left, there I can see what I need. But the cheapest version costs $759 there, looks scary for a hobby project of an east-european student :-(

Comment: Feature-rich and KISS?  Do you realize those are basically the exact opposites?

Comment: Matthew, I am pretty sure you're wrong in this. This is a matter of architecture, good concept design made before coding. A very feature rich and generally huge systems can be very KISSy if clear and efficient structure design is developed and flowed all throughout the code.

Comment: Just dump the data from C# and then use Asymptote language to render the beautiful 2D/3D graphics. I am serial! http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3D%20graphs/index.html

Answer (score 6):

The [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) are free and very powerful. Microsoft bought the rights to the Dundas chart control and repackaged it. Is it simple? No, it's a very powerful control. But Microsoft also has good documentation and [samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) for it. The samples make it appear to be just bar/pie/etc type charts, but it can handle math oriented charting as well.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was distracted by samples, I didn't know they are suitable for scientific charting. But as far as I can see the library is targeting .Net 3.5 and VS 2008. I am using .Net 4 and VS 2010. Will try anyway. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, the chart control is included with .NET 4. Open up the toolbox in VS2010 and you'll see it in the data section.

Answer (score 1):

[ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net/) is quite easy to learn (unfortunately, seems current version is not free). It combines a mathematical engine with visualization capabilities (providing Windows Forms Controls). Here is an example of a 3D scatter plot:

```
var colors
  = new[] { Color.Red, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Green /*...*/ };

ILArray<float> data = ILMath.zeros<float>(
  3,
  colors.Length);

ILArray<float> colorData = ILMath.zeros<float>(
  3,
  colors.Length);

int index = 0;
foreach (var p in colors)
{
  data[0, index] = p.GetHue();
  data[1, index] = p.GetSaturation();
  data[2, index] = p.GetBrightness();
  colorData [0, index] = p.R / 255.0f;
  colorData [1, index] = p.G / 255.0f;
  colorData [2, index] = p.B / 255.0f;
  index++;
}

var points = new ILPoints()
{
  Positions = data,
  Colors = colorData 
};

points.Color = null;

var plot = new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false)
{
  Rotation = Matrix4.Rotation(new Vector3(1, 1, 0.1f), 0.4f),
  Projection = Projection.Orthographic,
  Children = { points }
};

plot.Axes[0].Label.Text = "Hue";
plot.Axes[1].Label.Text = "Saturation";
plot.Axes[2].Label.Text = "Brightness";

this.ilPanel1.Scene = new ILScene { plot };
```

Comment: Ilnumeric seems to be a commercial product right? How much does it cost?

Comment: @user1234440 Definitely I didn't pay for it. So either there was a free version earlier, or I've used a trial - honestly I don't remember. Thanks for the notification - I'll update the answer.

Comment: im new to C# and the library is pretty amazing but then I see all people using it not sure if it requries paying or anything. I was able to get it and use it through nuget.

Answer (score 1):

Opensource tool :

http://plplot.sourceforge.net/index.php

However, the code is in C.

Comment: I created .Net bindings for PLplot at https://github.com/DeepMLNet/PLplotNet

Answer (score 0):

[ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) is fast, feature rich and easy to use. its my favorite charting control.

Comment: ZedGraph is 2D-only (y=f(x)). And not enough simple to be quickly extended to plot 3d (z=f(x,y)) data. I definitely need to plot real 3d (z=f(x,y))

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to interface to the [R programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) from C# as at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RtoCSharp.aspx.

There's a lot of examples of graphs [here](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/) which you may be able to convert to C# to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

The plplot package might do what you want. More details are here:
http://plplot.sourceforge.net/

Comment: no .NET binding