# Does Data.Visualization.Charting allow true "surface" plot?

Tags: c#, charts

I can only see "3D" versions of certain "2D" ChartTypes.

Is it possible to draw and rotate a proper 3D surface in .Net Data Visualization Charting?

Comment: No. Only 2d charttypes.

Comment: Wow. That's quite a missing feature. Is Data.Visualization.Charting NOT the best free library to use? I use to use ZedGraph but that doesn't seemed to be supported anymore

Comment: Well it is not so much a free library but an integrated part of the .Net framework(s).

Comment: True. But you would have thought surfaces plot would be popular

Comment: I'm sure they would be.. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748897/looking-for-framework-for-plotting-scientific-data-2d-3d?rq=1) doesn't yield anything free either